# Check value of async observable when entering page

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework

**Goal:** My goal is to check whether the user has an internet connection when they open the page. If they don't, I want a function to execute that opens a modal telling them to connect.

**Research:** I found an async function that checks whether an internet connection is available. I'm also able to display the status correctly on the webpage, but when I attempt to check the value of the status boolean, it is always false since the check is done asynchronously.

```
    online$: Observable<boolean>;

// Function runs when page is loaded
    checkInternet() {
            this.online$ = merge(
              of(navigator.onLine),
              fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(mapTo(true)),
              fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(mapTo(false))
            );
          }
```

HTML displays status correctly

```
<p>{{online$ | async}}</p>
```

**Question:** How can I check the value of online$ asynchronously in typescript and launch the modal if false?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do this in the app.component.ts file within the onInit hook.
This way it will live in your entire application and you can display your message whenever needed without being stuck to a specific page implementation.

Comment: I will definitely do this, thanks!

Any idea on how to check the value in typescript?